# How to use react dates properly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-dates

I'm having trouble with react dates. I end  up with this warning:

```
Failed prop type: The prop `startDateId` is marked as required in `withStyles(DateRangePicker)`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Per the documentation, it states that you need to use this command:

```
npm install --save react-dates moment@>=#.## react@>=#.## react-dom@>=#.## react-addons-shallow-compare@>=#.##
```

I assume that the hashes represent the version that you're to use and since they haven't specified any, it should work with the latest ones.

The version i use are the following:

```
"react-dates": "^16.0.1", "moment": "^2.20.1", "react": "^16.2.0", "react-dom": "^16.2.0", "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2"
```

In my component i have the following:

```
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
import 'react-dates/initialize';
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-dates";

<DateRangePicker
  startDate={this.props.filters.startDate}
  endDate={this.props.filters.endDate}
  onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
  focusedInput={this.state.calendarFocused}
  onFocusChange={this.onFocusChanged}
/>
```

Can anyone tell me anything as to why im getting this error and how to remove it please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking over the [source code](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/9780545c35831d793032538243bf560f254bbe60/src/shapes/DateRangePickerShape.js#L27) in v16.0.1, the `startDateId` is <strike>no longer</strike> a `required` prop for `DateRangePickerInput`.

The prop is found in DateRangePickerShape.js

Basically, the fix would be to add an id to the component like this:

```
<DateRangePicker
  startDateId="MyDatePicker"
  startDate={this.props.filters.startDate}
  endDate={this.props.filters.endDate}
  onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
  focusedInput={this.state.calendarFocused}
  onFocusChange={this.onFocusChanged}
/>
```

Comment: I've removed the node_modules and did a fresh install. I still get the same error. I never set the startDateId anywhere, as in the documentation it just stays to do what i've done. Any other advice on what could be wrong?

Comment: @strahinja i've edited my response accordingly, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much! Fixed!

Comment: They are both required in the TypeScript definitions